# Device Selection shows Loading... in Android Studio 4.0.1

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Flutter project in Android Studio is not able to Run in my Android Device. In Android Studio shows Loading in Flutter Devices Selection section.

[image]

In my case `flutter doctor` is showing everything ok for Android project setup. `flutter devices` shows 1 device connected.

[image]
[image]

I did apply Android Studio restart, did Invalidate Cache & Restart steps. But still not working.

Kindly help me if I missed any steps.

Comment: run adb devices from command prompt while Android Studio is on.

Comment: Yes @HBS It shows 1 device connected. Got below result


List of devices attached
ce051715b2f9512b02      device

Answer (score 0):

> My problem has been solved, this should be the official problem, I
> replaced the Flutter SDK, which has solved my problem, I hope to help
> you :-)

Comment: `Replaced the Flutter SDK` here you mean change the path of the Flutter SDK or just re-import the SDK again?

Comment: could you modify answer like that, SDK and plugin are two different thing.

Comment: I have uninstalled plugin and sdk and dart sdk and imported again. But still facing same issue.